# Find all reference to variable where it is set but not read in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a variable in my application that represents its configuration. There are many places where it is read but not set. I have found that I want to serialize the configuration in places where it is set.

In Visual Studio 2015 you can right click on a variable and "Find All References" which shows everywhere that the variable is used. But I would like to find only everywhere it is set but not read from.

*Is this possible?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution: slap a `const` on it and see where the compiler complains.

Comment: Well, that's a great idea.